# R: Pivot_Wider/spread by obtaining average sorted by year

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, pivot, spread

I've the following dataset

| Pet Shop | Year | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021 | dog | 300 |
| A | 2021 | dog | 250 |
| A | 2021 | fish | 20 |
| A | 2020 | turtle | 50 |
| A | 2020 | dog | 250 |
| A | 2020 | cat | 280 |
| A | 2019 | rabbit | 180 |
| A | 2019 | cat | 165 |
| A | 2019 | cat | 270 |
| B | 2021 | dog | 350 |
| B | 2021 | fish | 80 |
| B | 2021 | fish | 70 |
| B | 2020 | cat | 220 |
| B | 2020 | turtle | 90 |
| B | 2020 | turtle | 80 |
| B | 2020 | fish | 55 |
| B | 2019 | fish | 75 |
| C | 2021 | dog | 280 |
| C | 2020 | cat | 260 |
| C | 2020 | cat | 270 |
| C | 2019 | fish | 65 |
| C | 2019 | cat | 270 |

The code for the data is as follows

```
Pet_Shop = c(rep("A",9), rep("B",8), rep("C",5))
Item = c("Dog","Dog","Fish","Turtle","Dog","Cat","Rabbit","Cat","Cat","Dog","Fish","Fish","Cat","Turtle","Turtle","Fish","Fish","Dog","Cat","Cat","Fish","Cat")
Price = c(300,250,20,50,250,280,180,165,270,350,80,70,220,90,80,55,75,280,260,270,65,270)
Data = data.frame(Pet_Shop, Item, Price)
```

Does anyone here know how I can use pivot_wider or spread (or any other method) to achieve the following table? It groups the Shop by year and takes the average of the similar item of the same shop for the year. I've issues incorporating the year.

| Pet Shop | Year | dog | fish | turtle | cat | rabbit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021 | Average(300,250) = 275 | 20 | NA | NA | NA |
| A | 2020 | 250 | NA | 50 | 280 | NA |
| A | 2019 | NA | NA | NA | 217.5 | NA |
| B | 2021 | 350 | 75 | NA | NA | NA |
| B | 2020 | NA | 55 | 85 | 220 | NA |
| B | 2019 | NA | 75 | NA | NA | NA |
| C | 2021 | 280 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| C | 2020 | NA | NA | NA | 265 | NA |
| C | 2019 | NA | 60 | NA | 270 | NA |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pivot_wider` you may pass a function `(values_fn`) to be applied to each combination of `Pet_Shop` and `Year`.

```
result <- tidyr::pivot_wider(Data, names_from = Item, 
                             values_from = Price, values_fn = mean)
result

#  Pet_Shop  Year   dog  fish turtle   cat rabbit
#  <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A         2021   275    20     NA   NA      NA
#2 A         2020   250    NA     50  280      NA
#3 A         2019    NA    NA     NA  218.    180
#4 B         2021   350    75     NA   NA      NA
#5 B         2020    NA    55     85  220      NA
#6 B         2019    NA    75     NA   NA      NA
#7 C         2021   280    NA     NA   NA      NA
#8 C         2020    NA    NA     NA  265      NA
#9 C         2019    NA    65     NA  270      NA
```

The same can also be done with `data.table` `dcast` -

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(Data), Pet_Shop + Year ~ Item, 
      value.var = "Price", fun.aggregate = mean)
```